# Convert a given datetime to UTC time based on time zone description in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have data like the following. The first column is of the type `datetime`, and the second column is the corresponding time zone info, and is of the type `nvarchar`.

```
07/04/2012 14:20:45   EASTERN STANDARD TIME
07/04/2012 13:55:10   INDIAN STANDARD TIME
07/04/2012 10:55:00   CENTRAL STANDARD TIME
```

How can I convert the datetime column value of all the rows to UTC time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I could solve: CLR SQL

http://weblogs.asp.net/farhank/archive/2008/07/04/creating-clr-sql-user-defined-function-to-validate-values-using-regular-expression.aspx

(configuring the db)
http://exacthelp.blogspot.in/2012/02/create-assembly-for-assembly-failed.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
UPDATE dbo.YourTable
SET DateTimeColumn=CASE TimeShift 
                        WHEN N'EASTERN STANDARD TIME'
                             THEN DATEADD(hour,EasternTimeShift,DateTimeColumn)
                        WHEN N'INDIAN STANDARD TIME'
                             THEN DATEADD(hour,IndianTimeShift,DateTimeColumn)
                        ...
                        ELSE DateTimeColumn
                    END
```

Comment: Thank you @Igor, is there a better way?

Comment: Also, that would not consider of DST. This is totally achievable in C#, but I need this in SQL.

Comment: @VenkatRenukaPrasad What is DST? If you have a C# function for this you can create the same in T-SQL and use it in `SET` statement.

Comment: DST is Daylight savings time. It varies with a timezone, and even with in a timezone often. DateTimeOffset and TimeZoneInfo in C# take care of DST automatically.